# Different behaviours when executing a batch script

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, batch-file, registry

I created a batch script that installs some .vsix extensions and launches visual studio.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
start /wait VSIXInstaller.exe /q ABC.vsix
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

When I execute the script by double clicking, it works perfectly.

The next thing I wanted to do is to launch the script at windows startup.

I added an entry in the registry, here :

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Microsoft -> Windows - CurrentVersion -> Run`

I restared my machine and when windows started up, the script was executed but Visual Studio was launched before the installation of the vsix (extensions).

Why I have different behaviours when running the script directly and when it is started by windows ?

Is there something I have to do to correct that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VSIXInstaller.exe` is started without full path. Therefore Windows searches for such an application first in current working directory and next in all directories as defined in environment variable **PATH**.

I suppose that list of directories in **PATH** differ.

Or the working directory, also called `Start in` directory, is different as it is not possible to define a working directory for applications or batch files started via Windows registry entry `Run`.

The solution is to specify `VSIXInstaller.exe` with complete path in double quotes if needed which then requires also a title in double quotes for command `start`.

```
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
start "Install VSIX Extensions" /wait "Path to\VSIXInstaller\VSIXInstaller.exe" /q ABC.vsix
start "Configure IDE Environment" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

Hint: To find out what happens on execution of this batch file on Windows startup, specify in Windows registry a different batch file which contains the commands:

```
echo Working directory is %CD% 1>"C:\Temp\BatchStdout.txt"
call "Full\Path\To\Above\BatchFile.bat" 1>>"C:\Temp\BatchStdout.txt" 2>"C:\Temp\BatchStderr.txt"
```

Restart Windows and look on the files `BatchStdout.txt` and `BatchStderr.txt` created in directory `C:\Temp` which of course must already exist before Windows restart.

By the way: If this batch file should not run for all user accounts, it would be better to use

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Or you put a shortcut to the batch file into the folder `Startup` of the Windows start menu (all users profile or your user profile).

I would prefer the `Startup` folder instead of a Windows registry `Run` entry for such a task.